# Violated - parent key not found 02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am developing a database in Oracle SQL dev, that is trying to access foriegn keys from another table. I am currently working on the ItemOrdered table which I've created with the following CREATE statement

```
CREATE TABLE ItemOrdered(OrderID varchar2(9) REFERENCES Ords(OrderID),
BeltID varchar2(9) REFERENCES BeltID(BeltID), 
Quantity varchar(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(OrderID, BeltID))
```

As you can See I have the following foriegn keys Ords and BeltID.

Now when I try to run the following statement

```
INSERT INTO ItemOrdered VALUES(401565981,234489212,'2')
```

It gives me the following error

> violated - parent key not found
>   02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"

I have provided my Ords CREATE statement if its needed

```
  CREATE TABLE Ords(OrderID varchar2(9) PRIMARY KEY, 
CustomerID varchar(9) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID), 
    Expected_Delivery_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, 
Actual_Delivery_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, 
    Payment_Due_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, 
Order_Date date DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL, Price Varchar(10), 
    Order_Placed varchar2(1) CONSTRAINT OrderPlaced 
CHECK(Order_Placed IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL, 
Order_Confirmed varchar2(1)
    CONSTRAINT Order_Confirmed CHECK(Order_Confirmed IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL, 
Order_Completed varchar2(1) CONSTRAINT Order_Completed
    CHECK(Order_Completed IN('Y','N')) NOT NULL)
```

And I have also provided my BeltID CREATE statement

```
    CREATE TABLE BeltID(BeltID varchar2(9) PRIMARY KEY, 
BeltLengthID varchar2(9) REFERENCES BeltLength(BeltLengthID), 
    ColourID varchar2(9) REFERENCES Colour(ColourID), 
DesignID varchar2(9) REFERENCES Design(DesignID),ComponentID varchar2(9) REFERENCES Component(ComponentID))
```

I don't seem to quite understand why I am getting this error. Is there an clear explanation why?

Here is the http link of what I am trying to do. 
[link text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUflg.jpg)

Comment: Please indent your question. The SQL queries are very long - split them to more lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the foreign key constraints you specified when you created table ItemOrdered, when you perform this insert:

```
INSERT INTO ItemOrdered VALUES(401565981,234489212,'2')
```

... the values 401565981 and 234489212 must correspond to key values in the Ords and BelitId tables respectively - i.e. these 2 queries should return rows:

```
select *
from Ords
where OrderId = 401565981;

select *
from BeltId
where BeltId = 234489212;
```

The error message suggests this is not the case.

Comment: I have edited the post which contains a hyperlink to show an example of what I am trying to do. Looking at the image you can see ComplaintID and DepartmentID. I am trying to now implement what I had done in the Complaint table but with ItemeOrdered. I supplied the hyperlink to make things a little more clearer.

Comment: Sorry, but the hyperlink doesn't make anthing clearer to me!  What you are trying to do is insert data into a table that has foreign keys, and you are getting a foreign key violation.  Obviously I don't know your level of knowledge, so I apologise if this sounds rude but - do you know what a foreign key is?

Comment: Yes I do, a foreign key is a referential constraint between two tables. All that I am simply trying to do is access the BeltID and OrdsID from the parent table and make them a composite key as shown above. Having stated in your first answer highlighted that "the values 401565981 and 234489212 must correspond to key values in the Ords and BelitId tables" Having looked at my tables and the values in both Ords and BeltID both values do correspond.

Comment: The error message should tell you the name of the constraint that was violated e.g. "integrity constraint (MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE_FK1) violated - parent key not found".  It should not actually say "%s.%s".  Do you actually get "%s.%s" in the message?

Comment: Yes I do get the "%s.%s" message here is a hyperlink of what I am currently working on http://pastebin.com/B7uYHe4J

Comment: I can't make much of that either.  Your script seems to create a table, populate it, select from it, then drop it.  Then it tries to create a second table that references the first, which has just been dropped?  That's not going to work...

Comment: Yes your right I am creating the tables and populating it and selecting it. I put drop statement there just in case I made a mistake and a table needed to be dropped. Sorry for the confusion. I've supplied the link without the drop statements. I'm not sure if this makes it a bit http://pastebin.com/WfcXp30k

Answer (score 1):

I have no Oracle installation available so I can't test, but does it matter if you enclose the OrderID and BeltID in single quotes (which you should do anyway since the columns are declared as varchars)? I haven't tested it, but one idea would be that Oracle barfs on the fact that you are inserting a numeric value into a varchar column.

```
insert 
  into ItemOrdered VALUES('401565981', '234489212','2')
```

Another option would be that the order of the columns in the table does not correspond to the order you gave them in the insert statement. To rule this out, try rewrite the statement as:

```
insert 
  into ItemOrdered(OrderID,BeltID,Quantity) values('401565981', '234489212','2')
```

Comment: I tried not enclosing the OrderID and BeltID with single quotes. I did try this and it still provided the same error, as with the other option.