# ORA-02291:INTEGRITY CONSTRAINT (SYSTEM.SYS_C007150) VIOLATED - PARENT KEY NOT FOUND

Tags: sql, oracle

When I create the table `EMPLOYEE`, I made `ESSN` as a primary key and the `SUPERSSN` a foreign key from the same table with `DNO` as a foreign key from the dep table, when I want to insert values that show up and now I am confused.

The table contains the following:

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 ENAME                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 ESSN                                      NOT NULL CHAR(14)
 BDATE                                              DATE
 DNO                                                NUMBER(38)
 SUPERSSN                                           CHAR(14)
```

in first time I used the following command line:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE ('JOSEPH','789456','14-DEC-1986','3','123');
```

then I try without `DNO` as that:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ENAME,ESSN,BDATE)

  2  VALUES('JOSEPH','9861050560','14-DEC-1986');
-------------------------------
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ENAME,ESSN,BDATE)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C007150) violated - parent key not
found
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely parent_key record which is `SUPERSSN`(assuming) must be missing in parent table. You can find that out by

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_constraints
 WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
```

So you need to first insert values in parent table of employees table and then insert values in child table.

To find out parent_table do as

```
SELECT    uc.constraint_name
         || CHR (10)
         || '('
         || ucc1.TABLE_NAME
         || '.'
         || ucc1.column_name
         || ')'
            constraint_source,
            'REFERENCES'
         || CHR (10)
         || '('
         || ucc2.TABLE_NAME
         || '.'
         || ucc2.column_name
         || ')'
            references_column
   FROM user_constraints uc, user_cons_columns ucc1, user_cons_columns ucc2
   WHERE uc.constraint_name = ucc1.constraint_name
   AND uc.r_constraint_name = ucc2.constraint_name
   AND ucc1.POSITION = ucc2.POSITION 
   AND UC.TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEE'
   AND uc.constraint_type = 'R'
```

For more details please have a look at [this](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/03/05/validating-foreign-keys/).

And go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367047/violated-parent-key-not-found-02291-00000-integrity-constraint) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367047/violated-parent-key-not-found-02291-00000-integrity-constraint) as well.

Comment: i know  the primary key and the foreign key references 
i have for now only tow table (dep,employee)
even when i want to insert values for dep in first its give me the same error msg 
*note: dep table dont have any foreign key,just 4 columns and one of them called dnumber as a primary key.which is dno as foreign key in employee table.
thanx for helping

Comment: CONSTRAINT_SOURCE
-------------------------------

REFERENCES_COLUMN
----------------------------

SYS_C007149
(EMPLOYEE.SUPERSSN)
REFERENCES
(EMPLOYEE.ESSN)

SYS_C007150
(EMPLOYEE.DNO)
REFERENCES
(DEP.DNUMBER)

CONSTRAINT_SOURCE
-----------------------

REFERENCES_COLUMN
-------------------------

SQL> desc dep;
 
SQL> insert into dep
  2  values('hr','1','12345','10/4/2000');
insert into dep
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C007151) violated - parent key not
found

Comment: You should query the constraint name which is being thrown with this insertion into the dep table.  Specifically, like this: SELECT * FROM all_cons_columns acc WHERE acc.constraint_name = 'SYS_C007151';  This should shed some light on what needs to be done.

Comment: Of course you can view this by choosing the "Constraints" tab after opening a given table in SQL Developer, but I like the results your query shows better @user75ponic as they eliminate a lot of the extra details.

Answer (score 1):

I think the new entry(having foreign key constraint) you are entering is referring to an entry which doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query you could use to check to see if the values in your foreign key table exist or not, and of course if they do not exist then they would have to be inserted to resolve the parent key violation:

```
SELECT E.* FROM EMPLOYEE E 
    LEFT JOIN SUPER_TABLE S
        ON E.SUPERSSN = S.SUPERSSN 
WHERE S.SUPERSSN IS NULL AND E.SUPERSSN IS NOT NULL;
```

Of course, that is assuming the problem is with the SUPERSSN key.  If you have other foreign keys, then you may have to check those as well.